# Make canvas with shape responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I created a canvas with a circle inside and filled it with a gradient.

I am not sure how to make the canvas as well as the circle inside the canvas responsive to the screen size.

I tried using `vh` and `vw` for the width and height of the canvas. But when I change the height or width of the window, the circle looks either too long or too wide.

**Question:**

I want the entire circle to decrease in size when the window size is reduced. I am not sure how to do this.

**Code:**

---

```js
var c = document.getElementById('canvassun');
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
var grd = ctx.createRadialGradient(85, 85, 20, 85, 85, 70);
grd.addColorStop(0, 'red');
grd.addColorStop(0.5, 'orange');
grd.addColorStop(0.8, 'yellow');
grd.addColorStop(1, 'white');
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillStyle = grd;
ctx.arc(90, 90, 70, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath;
```

```css
#canvassun {
  height: 30vh;
  width: 14vw;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 18%;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvassun" width=170 height=170></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2):

Listen to window [resize event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onresize.asp) and redraw the canvas

```
function draw() {
  var c = document.getElementById('canvassun');
  var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
  var grd = ctx.createRadialGradient(85, 85, 20, 85, 85, 70);
  grd.addColorStop(0, 'red');
  grd.addColorStop(0.5, 'orange');
  grd.addColorStop(0.8, 'yellow');
  grd.addColorStop(1, 'white');
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle = grd;
  ctx.arc(90, 90, 70, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath;
}


window.addEventListener("resize", draw);
```

**Note** Probably you need to [debounce](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function) the `draw` function for performance